# Wordpress plugin, action hooks

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi fellas I'm starting to develop a wordpress plugin, I need a hook for an action to run before or after every post item, on the home page. I'm new to it and don't know if this is possible, I couldn't find the right one in API.

Comment: do you need to display something before/after each post you mean?

Comment: yes, I need to run function, before or after the post items on home page.

Comment: Can't you call the function within the loop on the homepage template?  If the function is in your functions.php file you can call it directly, otherwise you need to include the file containing the function first.

Comment: Of course I can, but I want to wrap my functionality in the plugin so others can use it...

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out myself. In case anyone needs it, the hook name is `the_post` it runs a function before every post.

```
add_action('the_post','myFunc');
```